# How to using ajax function in calendar event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, calendar

My JS code Here

```
type = "t1";
$(document).ready(function(){
getServiceFeed(type);
});
function getServiceFeed(type){
    typeshow = type;
    console.log(typeshow);
    $('.calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },

    height: 540,
    editable: false,
    eventLimit: true, 
    events:
    {
        type: "POST",
        data: 'typeshow='+typeshow,
        url: 'svFeed.php',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(typeshow);
        }
    },
    timeFormat: 'H:mm',

    loading: function(bool) {
        $('#loading').toggle(bool);
    },
    eventClick: function(event) {
        if (event.describe) {
            alert(event.describe);
            return false;
        }
    }
});
}
```

My HTML Code Here

```
<button onclick="getServiceFeed('t1')" >Public</button>
<button onclick="getServiceFeed('t2')" >Self</button>
<button onclick="getServiceFeed('t3')" >Private</button>
```

I want change event in my calendar when I click button. I try using above code, still display 't1' calendar only. I try to using console.log() for debug, just only display once, the 1st typeshow, that's mean no running calendar.

Comment: Don't close the button tag before the content. Use `<button onclick="getServiceFeed('t1')" >` .

Comment: Is the value of typeshow changing according to the button you press?

Comment: yes, I click self, the 1st console.log() will display 't2', but inside calendar console.log() no show.

Answer (score 0):

My reputation is not enough to comment so I am writing it as an answer.

Your **success callback** is not running because you are getting **error callback**.

Write **error callback** also in events object so you can fix that error then you will get **success callback**.

Comment: I add a code like this `error: function(data) {
               console.log(data);
            },`
still cannot get and data

Comment: I try your code, just only get event at once (when the page load), but I need when I click the button (like click button private) , the calendar will clear the previously event and get the (private) event details show on calendar@Manaj Verma

Comment: I just wrote code to solve your problem of not printing t2 t3 when pressing the button in success callback. Actually, in my code, I have given the URL of a dummy API which returns some data. You will use your events API URL there and load calendar with return data.